# a[lst+1][item] causes an error while a[lst-1][item] is fine

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = [[".",".",".",".","."],[".",".","O",".","."],[".",".",".",".","."],\
     [".",".",".",".","."],[".",".",".",".","."]]

def detect():
    global a
    for nm_lst, lst in enumerate(a):
        for nm_item, item in enumerate(lst):
            if item == "O":
                move(nm_lst,nm_item)

def move(lst,item):
    global a
    a[lst][item] = "."
    if inp == "w":
        if lst == 0:
            a[lst][item] = "O"
        else:
            a[lst-1][item] = "O"
    elif inp == "s":
            a[lst+1][item] = "O"

def print_board(board):
    for smthng in board:
        new = " ".join(smthng)
        print(new)
def game():
    global inp
    print_board(a)
    inp = input("w/a/s/d: ")
    detect()
while True:
    game()
```

When I press "s" on the first move I get an error:

```
a[lst+1][item] = "O"
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This does not make sense to me as I have tried printing `lst+1` instead of doing `a[lst+1]` and it gave `"2"` which should work just fine because `a[2][number]` does not give an error.

I know people will say: "you are exceeding the limit when you make a couple of moves", so I repeat; I press `"s"` on the first move. I tried it, and I found out that no matter what lst is when you do `lst+1` here it gives an error.

I created a new file and just coded a `list` and tried to use `lst+1` there. It worked just fine.

I am sorry if this is a stupid question (probably is). I posted the whole code because I have no idea where I could have possibly messed up.

Comment: It's not that [2][2] is causing the error, but rather [5][2].  The loop you use in `detect` is pushing the first index out of bounds.  Your global variables (`inp` specifically) are causing/will cause you these sorts of weird hard-to-identify bugs -- try to restructure your program to eliminate these.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? It looks like by changing `a[lst+1][item] = "O"`, `move()` will be called multiple times on line 9 since `item` is changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `a[lst+1][item] = "O"`, the detect function is still in a loop and will iterate over that next item again `if item == "O":` until you get to the last index in `a` and return an index error. You should do

`if item == "O":
    move(nm_lst,nm_item)
    return`

to check for the next input.